# How to use Ant design v5 theme with style component

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

Antd 5.0 has been introduced their new theme system.
But I wonder how to access to those design tokens of theme when I declare a component by style-component.
normally I declare my component like this.

```
const MyComponent = styled.button`
  color:${props=> props.theme.color.primary};
`;
```

`theme` here is getting from `ThemeProvider` of styled component that is defined in `App.jsx`

```
<ThemeProvider theme={baseTheme}>
<App/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

So, theme only can access to design tokens that were defined in theme file.
How can I access other tokens of Antd theme?

One way I'm thinking is creating a theme that overrides every single design token of Antd. But I think that's a bad idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation [consume-design-token](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#consume-design-token), you can get and consume the token by using the `theme.useToken()` hook.

Create a `ThemeProvider` get the antd theme token and combine it with base theme, then pass the combined theme to the `ThemeProvider` of `styled-components`.

Then you can get the combined theme via [passed props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) of `styled-components`.

`theme-provider.tsx`:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { theme } from "antd";
import React from "react";

export default ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  const { token } = theme.useToken();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{ antd: token, base: { color: "mediumseagreen" } }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import ThemeProvider from "./theme-provider";

const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${(props) => {
    console.log("props.theme: ", props.theme);
    return props.theme.antd.colorPrimary;
  }};
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        token: {
          colorPrimary: "red"
        }
      }}
    >
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Button>Hello World</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}
```

The log:

```bash
props.theme:  {antd: Object, base: Object}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-75067909-qjzg6m)